# ZBash - expand a wildcard result into a string variable

Tags: bash

i've been struggling with this.

```
folder_path=$home_directory/"Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-"*
```

now, if i do so something like this

```
x=$folder_path
echo "x:"   $x
```

the result will be

```
x: /Users/userX/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-first.lastname@company
```

but actually this "x" is not really a string - it seems that only became a string on echo.
how can i actually set a variable with the "result" ?

because if try todo something like this

```
folder="a"
echo ${x}/${folder}
```

the output is

```
/Users/userX/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-*/a
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What is Zbash? Do you mean zsh?

Comment: (zsh is a completely different shell from bash; it's not a variant but a completely independently developed and incompatible piece of software with conflicting design priorities and rationale).

Comment: Anyhow, if you want to expand at assignment time, expand _into an array_. That is, if you use `x=( ~/"Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-"* )`, **that** will be expanded at assignment time. (It may have more than one result -- you'll want to check its length and iterate if there are multiple matches; also, note that if there are no matches at all, the default behavior is to evaluate to the glob expression itself).

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are not expanded when assigning to a variable.

Assign the result of a command:

```
folder_path=$(printf '%s\n' "$home_directory/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-"*)
```

Comment: This'll behave... interestingly... if there's more than one match, concatenating the results into a single string with no whitespace between entries.

Comment: Added a newline. Although for their intended use I don't think multiple matches will work.

Comment: Agreed. All the more reason to explicitly test for and handle the case, though, no?